# How to get two greatest number in postgresql?

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have four columns (col1,col2,col3,col4)
or four numbers(78,98,56,110).
I need the first two greatest number using SQL.

Comment: Which one is it, for columns or four numbers or do you mean four columns with numbers? What have you tried and what is the actual issue here? Comparing number should be trivial.

Answer (score 0):

The `greatest()` is easy:

```
select greatest(col1, col2, col3, col4)
```

However, if you want two values, I'm going to recommend a lateral join:

```
select t.*, v.max_val, v.second_val
from t cross join lateral
     (select max(v.col) as max_val,
             (array_agg(v.col order by v.col desc))[2] as second_val
      from (values (t.col1), (t.col2), (t.col3), (t.col4)) v(col)
     ) v;
```

[Here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_11&fiddle=560371c878f75b47fd1840bfd5554ed8) is a db<>fiddle.

If you want to filter out `NULL` values, add a filter:

```
select t.*, v.max_val, v.second_val
from t cross join lateral
     (select max(v.col) as max_val,
             (array_agg(v.col order by v.col desc))[2] as second_val
      from (values (t.col1), (t.col2), (t.col3), (t.col4)) v(col)
      where v.col is not null
     ) v;
```

Or fix the ordering:

```
select t.*, v.max_val, v.second_val
from t cross join lateral
     (select max(v.col) as max_val,
             (array_agg(v.col order by v.col desc nulls last))[2] as second_val
      from (values (t.col1), (t.col2), (t.col3), (t.col4)) v(col)
     ) v;
```

Comment: Thank you for the query. I have four columns(col1,col2,col3,col4), the values of those columns are (56,85,null,null), but i get the output as, maxval as 85 and second_val as null??